# Predict a new row from a previous row

Tags: lstm, seq2seq

I have a dataset where the dataset is such that we have 4 columns with different values for each row where for certain columns the value might increase or decrease in the next row. I wanted to understand which model or ML type of problem is this where I want to predict a new row with 4 columns by looking at the data of previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question description, if you are planning to predict the next output in a sequence, then Recurrent Neural Networks seem to be an appropriate choice to go for. For example, prediction of stock prices, weather forecasting.

Now this answer wouldn't be a comprehensive guide to sequence prediction with RNNs and considering the wide spectrum of material available on the topic, I would suggest you to go through the following blog or the video which can be an intuitive starting point for understanding RNNs and beyond.

https://towardsdatascience.com/recurrent-neural-networks-d4642c9bc7ce

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNmqTiOnRfg&t=14s

Hope this helps!